# Restore Browser Session after Browser Restart (Duplicate Cookie issue)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, session, cookies

I want browser to restore my web application session after browser restart.
I am using the following code to do so :

```
HttpSession browserSession = request.getSession();
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("SESSION", browserSession.getId());
cookie.setMaxAge(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

Before I create the above SESSION cookie, there already exists a SESSION cookie when I run my application.

The browser session is restored only if I give its name as "SESSION", if I name it with some other name then cookie is created and it survives even if i restart the browser but the app session is not resumed.

Initially I tried to fetch and set the existing "SESSION" cookie value and max age but it didn't work.
I am able to resume browser session if I use the above code but there are 2 "SESSION" cookies.
Is there any way to maintain only 1 "SESSION" cookie?
Or is my approach wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is right. Don't worry about the duplicate cookies, because one will automatically be deleted with the browser session. And the other one(which you have set the age to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`) will stay in the cookie database.

When you visit the site again after restarting the browser, it will only have 1 SESSION cookie and the server will definitely allocate the specific session with the given id.

Tested in Apache Tomcat 8.0

Comment: Thank you for the reply. but having 2 cookies with same name is ok? will it coz problem in future?

Comment: There will only be one cookie after browser restart.

Comment: if i want to delete SESSION cookie created by me, how can i identify since both will have same name?

Comment: i want to delete the cookie at user logout.